# How to use Dynamic Parameters value in ccnet file

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I am using dynamic parameter  to get value from user when he force build.User provides me publish directory path where i have to publish the solution if build is successful, so can any one please tell me how can i get this value in publishDir section.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can refer your parameter by it's name, for example if your parameter name is pubdir then u can call it with following code.
$[pubdir] inside your publishdir section.